# Accessing InjectionPoint inside Spring functional bean definition DSL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, dsl

We use a Bean factory function to allow injection of Logger objects into our Beans.
This looks similar to what Simar Paul Singh describes in his article "[Inject loggers in Spring](https://medium.com/simars/inject-loggers-in-spring-java-or-kotlin-87162d02d068)"

```
import org.slf4j.*
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InjectionPoint
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*

@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
fun logger(injectionPoint: InjectionPoint): Logger {
  return LoggerFactory.getLogger(
      injectionPoint.methodParameter?.containingClass // constructor
          ?: injectionPoint.field?.declaringClass // or field injection
  )
}
```

Today I attempted to convert this declaration into a Bean declaration using [Springs functional bean definition DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/kotlin.html#bean-definition-dsl).  However I did not succeed to get a hold of the `InjectionPoint` used to retrieve the class the Logger is injected into.

```
import org.slf4j.*
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InjectionPoint
import org.springframework.context.support.beans
import org.springframework.context.support.BeanDefinitionDsl.Scope.PROTOTYPE

fun beans() = beans {
    bean(scope = PROTOTYPE) {
        val injectionPoint = ref<InjectionPoint>()
    
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(
            injectionPoint.methodParameter?.containingClass // constructor
                ?: injectionPoint.field?.declaringClass // or field injection
        )
    }
}
```

The above results in an exception along the lines of:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.InjectionPoint' available
```

Is there a way to retrieve the `InjectionPoint` or at least the class to provide a behaviour similar to the Bean declaration without DSL?

A minimal reproduction repository can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/EndzeitBegins/spring-bean-dsl-injection-point).
Run `./gradlew bootRun` or `.\gradlew.bat bootRun` on Windows to reproduce the error.

---

I've opened [issue #27738](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27738) on the GitHub repository of Spring.

Comment: will you be able to share your whole code or GitHub link for this?

Comment: @Raj I added a repository with a minimal reproduction to GitHub. See the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: *can* reproduce (..with annotation config, it works like charm)! please file an issue (best [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues) i think). Wait for fix/ stick to/mix with annotation config /star [Spring Fu](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-fu).

Comment: @xerx593 Thanks for you reply. I will probably file an issue in the GitHub repository for Spring soon. I know about and look forward to the advance "Spring Fu", which has been put on halt for now sadly.

Comment: ..i think, the guys (implementing DSL support) just forgot about that ([also in the Test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context/src/test/kotlin/org/springframework/context/support/BeanDefinitionDslTests.kt)) [The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/kdoc-api/spring-context/org.springframework.context.support/-bean-definition-dsl/-scope/-p-r-o-t-o-t-y-p-e/index.html) also needs some effort. (dead links, incorrect/copy&paste)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will get an instance of `InjectionPoint` because it is created in response to the demand a component makes for an injection of a managed bean.

`InjectionPoint` class is not annotated with `@Component` or any of its derivatives like `@Service`. Hence, it is not a managed bean and you will not get a reference using `ref<InjectionPoint>`.

`InjectionPoint` only contains meta information about the class or method that is requesting an instance of the managed bean. *That is, it not a functional object and hence, not managed.* However, it can be optionally accepted by the bean factory method to make some decisions about the instance to be returned. Hence, your bean factory method (whatever it is called in Kotlin) must accept an instance of `InjectionPoint`, which is what you are doing in your first version in the post.

Also, from the minimal I could understand from the docs of Kotlin Bean DSL [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/kdoc-api/spring-framework/org.springframework.context.support/-bean-definition-dsl/), I couldn't see **a way to accept it as a parameter** (but that could simply be due to my lack of knowledge of Kotlin. So, in summary, this may not be useful for bean definitions where injection point is needed, unless you can go through the docs and find out a way which I may have missed.

Comment: Thanks @SreeKumar, your answer does not help with my use case directly, but provides a good overview of the problem at hand. Thus, if no one comes with a more appropriate answer in the next hour, I will award the bounty to this answer. As it does not fully answer the question however, I will not mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Kotlin but can you please try this

```
fun beans() = beans {
    bean<InjectionPoint>()
    bean(scope = PROTOTYPE) {
        val injectionPoint = ref<InjectionPoint>()
    
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(
            injectionPoint.methodParameter?.containingClass // constructor
                ?: injectionPoint.field?.declaringClass // or field injection
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. After this, the call to `ref<InjectionPoint>()` no longer yields the aforementioned error, but is simply `null` which does not help in creating the Logger either.